# How to remove common values of one list from another using variables

Tags: bash, list, variables, edit

I have a multiple values stored in a variable (directory names). To view values I put them into a lst file.

```
for i in ' */ ' ; do
  echo $i > list.lst
done

###Turn row into column
fmt -1 list.lst > listColumns.lst
sed 's:/::g' listColumns.lst > predicted.lst


for data in $(cat predicted.lst) ; do
  predicted=$data
  #echo $predicted
done

###Get names of targets and assign to variable $targets
for names in $(cat targets.lst) ; do
  targets=$names
  #echo $targets
done



###Remove contents of $predicted from $targets and put into new list
grep -v "${predicted}" "${targets}" > targets2.lst
```

For the last part of actually removing $predicted from $targets I also tried using sed but with no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `for i in ' */ '` does not expand to directory names.
  You should not quote `*/`.
- `echo $i > list.lst` will overwrite existing file and the last element
  only remains. Besides you need to quote `"$i"`.
- `predicted=$data` will overwrite existing variable.

If you want to exclude existing directory names from `targets.lst`,
please try instead:

```
grep -Fxvf <(ls -d -1 */ | tr -d /) targets.lst
```

- The `-f` option to `grep` takes the 1st argument as a filename which includes the patterns.
- The `-Fx` option assures the exact match of the strings.
- `<(command ..)` is a process substitution behaving as if a file.
- `ls -d -1 */` prints directory names one per line.
- `tr -d /` removes the slashes.

**[Edit]**
If the process substitution does not work well for some reason, please try instead:

```
ls -d -1 */ | tr -d / | grep -Fxvf - targets.lst
```

where `grep -f -` specifies the standard input passed via the pipe as the pattern.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting very close. The above works when I enter it directly into the shell. However, when I run it within a bash script (update_list.sh) I receive the following:

**update_list.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('
update_list.sh: line 25: `grep -Fxvf <(ls -d -1 */ | tr -d /) ../heterodimer.lst > remaining_pred.lst'**

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Does the file `update_list.sh` have the shebang line (the first line) as `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer adding an alternative w/o the process substitution, which may be the cause of the error for some reason.

Comment: I'm using #!/bin/bash in .sh scripts and haven't had a problem with it.

That said! Your second solution worked perfectly. Thank you!